# How to align text of selected CellTable columns in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, gwt2

I want to right-align numeric values in a CellTable. I already tried looking for ways to assign a style name for selected columns so I could align it with CSS but still couldn't figure out.

[image]

I also tried this but didn't work,

```
itemPriceColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

According to the GWT documentation, the new horizontal alignment will apply the next time the table is rendered... and I don't know yet what parameters I have to pass since it is required by render() method.

So I'm hoping for answers that would involve CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, what you had is almost right. This works for me, without css: `myColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);`

Comment: That's the trouble with these huge frameworks.  They have everything you need.  But it's hard to find anything because there's so much stuff to dig through.

Answer (score 1):

```
unitPriceColumn.setCellStyleNames("alignRight");

totalAmountColumn.setCellStyleNames("alignRight");
```

Where `alignRight` is the name of your CSS.

```
.alignRight {text-align:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use float:right on the parent element (  in the CellTable).

Option 2: Create your own TextCell and implement render method to generate something like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;"> your value </div>
```